# HAProxy redirect traffic to NGINX getting error "The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port"

Tags: nginx, ssl, haproxy

What we are trying to is to have HAProxy to listen for all incoming traffic from port 443 (HTTPS & WSS)

Below is our HAProxy config:

```
frontend wwws
  bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/server.pem
  timeout client 1h
  default_backend www_backend

backend www_backend
  mode http
  stats enable
  stats uri /haproxy
  option forwardfor
  reqadd x-forwarded-proto:\ https

  server server1 backend:3000 weight 1 maxconn 8192 check
```

0.0.0.0:443 (e.g. https://example.com) is our HA proxy server listening for all incoming 443 traffic
backend:3000 is our nginx server which is set to listen for SSL connections

The current problem we are facing right now is when we enter https://example.com, the browser is showing the following error:

```
400 Bad Request
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
nginx/1.7.5
```

It does seems like when haproxy forward the traffic to nginx (backend:3000) it converts to http.

I thought "reqadd x-forwarded-proto:\ https " is suppose to make sure it is https.

Not sure what is wrong with our haproxy config.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change the backend server specification to this:

```
server server1 backend:3000 weight 1 maxconn 8192 check ssl verify none
```

The "ssl" part defines that the backend speaks SSL, if it is not present, haproxy will default to plain HTTP. The "verify none" disables certificate check, something you probably don't want to do with your internal servers anyway.

Comment: Perfectly worked +1